how do I access the returned fields in a TSQL Query using this Function 'NameParser'?
Could someone show an example of using this Function from within a t-sql statment as well as accessing the returned Fields.
Select StudentName, dbo.NameParser(StudentName)
  From StudentTable AS ST;

I need to find out how to access the individual fields returned in the table
original
Mrs. Thurston Howell, III
prefix
Mrs
firstName
Thurston
middleName
--BLANK--
lastName
Howell
suffix
III
Thanks so very much for you help.
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[NameParser]
(
    @name nvarchar(100)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (

WITH prep AS (
    SELECT 
        original = @name,
        cleanName = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(@name)),'  ',' '),'  ',' '), '.', ''), ',', '')
)
SELECT
    prep.original,
    aux.prefix,
    firstName.firstName,
    middleName.middleName,
    lastName.lastName,
    aux.suffix
FROM
    prep
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT 
            prefix =
                CASE 
                    WHEN LEFT(prep.cleanName, 3) IN ('MR ', 'MS ', 'DR ', 'FR ')
                        THEN LEFT(prep.cleanName, 2)
                    WHEN LEFT(prep.cleanName, 4) IN ('MRS ', 'LRD ', 'SIR ')
                        THEN LEFT(prep.cleanName, 3)
                    WHEN LEFT(prep.cleanName, 5) IN ('LORD ', 'LADY ', 'MISS ', 'PROF 
   ')
                        THEN LEFT(prep.cleanName, 4)
                    ELSE ''
                END,
            suffix =
                CASE 
                    WHEN RIGHT(prep.cleanName, 3) IN (' JR', ' SR', ' II', ' IV')
                        THEN RIGHT(prep.cleanName, 2)
                    WHEN RIGHT(prep.cleanName, 4) IN (' III', ' ESQ')
                        THEN RIGHT(prep.cleanName, 3)
                    ELSE ''
                END
    ) aux
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
            baseName = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(prep.cleanName, LEN(aux.prefix) + 1, 
            LEN(prep.cleanName) - LEN(aux.prefix) - LEN(aux.suffix)))),
            numParts = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM 
        STRING_SPLIT(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(prep.cleanName, LEN(aux.prefix) + 1, 
            LEN(prep.cleanName) - LEN(aux.prefix) - LEN(aux.suffix)))), ' '))
    ) core
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
            firstName = 
                CASE
                    WHEN core.numParts <= 1 THEN core.baseName
                    ELSE LEFT(core.baseName, CHARINDEX(' ', core.baseName, 1) - 1) 
                END

    ) firstName
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
            remainder = 
                CASE
                    WHEN core.numParts <= 1 THEN ''
                    ELSE LTRIM(SUBSTRING(core.baseName, LEN(firstName.firstName) + 1, 
 999999))
                END
    ) work1
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
            middleName = 
                CASE
                    WHEN core.numParts <= 2 THEN ''
                    ELSE LEFT(work1.remainder, CHARINDEX(' ', work1.remainder, 1) - 1) 
                END
    ) middleName
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
            lastName = 
                CASE
                    WHEN core.numParts <= 1 THEN ''
                    ELSE LTRIM(SUBSTRING(work1.remainder, LEN(middleName.middleName) + 
                         1, 999999))
                END
    ) lastName
)

GO

SELECT * FROM dbo.NameParser('Madonna')
SELECT * FROM dbo.NameParser('Will Smith')
SELECT * FROM dbo.NameParser('Neil Degrasse Tyson')
SELECT * FROM dbo.NameParser('Dr. Neil Degrasse Tyson')
SELECT * FROM dbo.NameParser('Mr. Hyde')
SELECT * FROM dbo.NameParser('Mrs. Thurston Howell, III')

Function Created By:
https://stackoverflow.com/users/3545738/charlienotomatoes
==========================================
I have come up with the following Select Statement
SELECT
   dbo.Name_Parser.original
 , dbo.Name_Parser.prefix
 , dbo.Name_Parser.firstName
 , dbo.Name_Parser.middleName
 , dbo.Name_Parser.lastName
 , dbo.Name_Parser.suffix
FROM dbo.Name_Parser('Mrs. Thurston Howell, III')

Which returns each of the fields that I need from the Function, Now what I need to know is how to wrap this in an Update Statement to update each of the Fields in the MSSQL Table with new values from the Function.  I know that the 'Mrs. Thurston Howell, III' is replaced with Full_Name Field from the Table, I just don't know how to reference each of the TableFields to receive the variables in the Select Statement.
 UPDATE StudentTable
 SET ST.Prefix = dbo.Name_Parser.prefix,
     ST.FirstName = dbo.Name_Parser.firstNam,
     ...

Where do I place the Select Statement from above within the Update Statement. ( Also I know that I have to replace 'Mrs. Thurston Howell, III' with ST.StudentName FieldName ).
Again, any useful help will be greatly appreciated.

If you are linking to a function created by someone else, you should be linking to where that source came from, not just the user's name. Otherwise, assuming that function was posted here on [so], you are not adhering to CC-by-SA.

That, however, is a table value function, not a scalar function. You reference it in the FROM, not the SELECT.

Something like: update t set Name = f.Name, FirstName = f.FirstName, Title = f.Title, SomeOtherMoniker = f.SomeOtherMoniker from yourtable t CROSS APPLY dbo.NameParser(StudentName) f
